# How to reduce line height using materialize css input fields

Tags: html, css

I would like to reduce the line high.
This is my Html code:
[The picture shows the results. Line spacing is high][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekecF.png`enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekecF.png%60enter) code here`

```
<div class="row">
<h3>List</h3>
</div> <!-- End Row -->
<!-- Header -->
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s1"><input value="N°" type="text" disabled></div>
<div class="input-field col s2"><input value="First name" type="text" disabled></div>
<div class="input-field col s3"> <input value='Last name' type="text"disabled></div>
</div>  <!-- End row ->>
<!-- Here user inserts details -->
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s1"><input value="1" type="text" disabled></div>
<div class="input-field col s2"><input value="" type="text"></div>
<div class="input-field col s3"> <input value="" type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create a codepen, as it will explain the question better.

Comment: @khalil. I provided the html code and a picture showing the result i got. I need to reduce the line height (line spacing). Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the css as well?

Comment: @khalil. i didn't use any css. Just used links of materializecss in the header of the html file.

Comment: You can reduce the `height` property of the input field and you can reduce the value the `transform: translateY(12px)` on the label, this will make the input field shorter

Comment: I created 2 styles:
  <style>
    .hauteur {
      line-height: 0.2em;
    }
    .hauteur2 {
      transform: translateY(10px)
    }
  </style>
Then applied as you informed:
  <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s1 hauteur">
        <input value="N°" type="text" disabled>
        <lable class="hauteur2"></label>
        </div>
   </div>
But still line spaces high.

Comment: Why are you using the `input` elements as labels by disabling them? plus where did take the classes `.hauteur` and `.hauteur2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with **materializecss** they have a bottom margin for every element.
here are elements with classes...

- here `margin-bottom:20px` in row class.
  [image: margin with .row]
- here `margin-bottom:1rem` in input-field class.
  [image: margin .input-field.col.s2]
- here `margin-bottom:8px` in input field.
  [image: margin with input field]

you have to change their margin. if **materializecss** have a class like `.m-0` means `margin:0;` like bootstrap then you have to use that else you have to use custom CSS to set every element's `margin-bottom:0;`